# Why is there a missing piece of line on the table?

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, line-spacing

I have the following table which for some reason doesn't display the complete LHS vertical end line. I've notice that the line 'broke' when I added the `\\`; I added `\\` because I wanted some space between the end-horizontal line and the fractions.  Could someone please help me to fix the line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{ | m{3.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{2.8cm}| } 
\hline
%\vspace{2mm}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Reciprocal identities :}}\\
\vspace{2mm} $\sin \theta = \dfrac{1}{\csc \theta}$ & \vspace{2mm} $\cos \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sec \theta}$ & \vspace{2mm} $\tan \theta = \dfrac{1}{\cot \theta}$\\
\vspace{3mm} $\csc \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sin \theta}$ & \vspace{2mm} $\sec \theta = \dfrac{1}{\cos \theta}$ & \vspace{2mm} $\cot \theta = \dfrac{1}{\tan \theta}$\\ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Also, how can I add space between the horizontal line and 'Reciprocal identities'? I tried `\vspace{2mm}` (with `%`)  but, once again, the line breaks and modifies the text to the center.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should put your tabular in a `\fbox` if you only want a box around the tabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\\[Xpt]` instead of `\\ \\` at the end of the last table line for considering some space between the last table line and the horizontal line. In this way, you can also adjust the space by changing the `X` value.

So, your code will be something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{ | m{3.5cm} m{3.5cm} m{2.8cm}| } 
\hline
%\vspace{2mm}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Reciprocal identities :}}\\
\vspace{2mm} $\sin \theta = \dfrac{1}{\csc \theta}$ & \vspace{2mm} $\cos \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sec \theta}$ & \vspace{2mm} $\tan \theta = \dfrac{1}{\cot \theta}$\\
\vspace{3mm} $\csc \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sin \theta}$ & \vspace{2mm} $\sec \theta = \dfrac{1}{\cos \theta}$ & \vspace{2mm} $\cot \theta = \dfrac{1}{\tan \theta}$ \\[20pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I also tried this after the first `\hline`, so `\hline \\ [2pt]`, to have space between the first line and `\textbf` and indeed displayed space but with a broken line too. Do you know how can be fixed?

Comment: You 're welcome! ;)
Actually, I don't have a clean trick for that! but I think that `\hline && \\[20pt]` will work as it adds an empty line to the table.

Comment: It worked too, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my suggestion using `framed` and an  `array` instead of the inner tabular:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{25pt}
  \begin{framed}
    \textbf{Reciprocal identities:}
    \[\begin{array}{cll} 
      \sin \theta = \dfrac{1}{\csc \theta} 
        &  \cos \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sec \theta} 
          &  \tan \theta = \dfrac{1}{\cot \theta}\\
      \csc \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sin \theta} 
        &  \sec \theta = \dfrac{1}{\cos \theta} 
          & \cot \theta = \dfrac{1}{\tan \theta}\\ 
    \end{array}\]
  \end{framed}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply forgot, adding an empty row, to add a *full* empty row.

I propose two other solutions, one using `cellspace`, which ensures a minimal spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier  prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C`  if you load `siunitx` and another entirely different, based on the `empheq` package, which enables to have boxed multilined equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}\fbox{\quad#1\quad}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |*{2}{>{$}m{3.5cm}<{$}}>{$}m{2.8cm}<{$}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{Reciprocal identities :}}\\
\vspace{2mm} \sin θ= \dfrac{1}{\csc θ}&\vspace{2mm} \cos θ= \dfrac{1}{\sec θ} & \vspace{2mm}\tan θ= \dfrac{1}{\cot θ}\\
\vspace{3mm} \csc θ= \dfrac{1}{\sin θ} & \vspace{2mm} \sec θ= \dfrac{1}{\cos θ} & \vspace{2mm} \cot θ= \dfrac{1}{\tan θ} \\ & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vskip1cm
\begin{tabular}{ |*{2}{>{$}S{m{3.5cm}}<{$}}>{$}S{m{2.8cm}}<{$}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|Sl|}{\textbf{Reciprocal identities :}}\\
 \sin θ= \dfrac{1}{\csc θ}& \cos θ= \dfrac{1}{\sec θ} &\tan θ= \dfrac{1}{\cot θ}\\
\csc θ= \dfrac{1}{\sin θ} & \sec θ= \dfrac{1}{\cos θ} & \cot θ= \dfrac{1}{\tan θ} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{empheq}[box = \widefbox]{align*}
 & \rlap{\textbf{Reciprocal identities :}}\\
 & \sin θ= \dfrac{1}{\csc θ}& & \cos θ= \dfrac{1}{\sec θ} & &\tan θ= \dfrac{1}{\cot θ}\\[1.5ex]
 & \csc θ= \dfrac{1}{\sin θ} & & \sec θ= \dfrac{1}{\cos θ} & & \cot θ= \dfrac{1}{\tan θ}
 \end{empheq}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir +1